# Assign date to another variable without changing initial date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How would I assign a (manipulated) date to a new variable without changing the initial date (`dateA`) using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ?

```
dateA = moment(); // 1 Jan 2015

dateB = dateA.add(2,'days');

// dateA:  3 Jan 2015...but should be 1 Jan 2015
// dateB: 3 Jan 2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating a `moment` by passing it a `moment` will clone it according to the documentation:

```
dateA = moment();
dateB = moment(dateA).add(2,'days');
```

You could also simply call the `clone` method:

```
dateA = moment();
dateB = dateA.clone().add(2,'days');
```

DOCS: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/